# Not able to understand the SQL equivalent of dplyr code

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

What is the equivalent SQL statement for the following dplyr code

```
df %>%
  select(c(patient_id, patient_name)) %>%
  rename(ID = patient_id, Name = patient_name)
```

Can someone explain to me in detail how to deal with this question?

Comment: And what is this code supposed to do? Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT    Patient_id AS ID,
          Patient_name AS name
FROM      Df
```